# how i to slove this "Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

this erreur[image]

im begginner in flutter i don't know how to slove this
this is my code :

Comment: share code where you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the height and width of the container.
For example:

`Container( height:50.0, width:50.0, child: ... )`

Comment: i slove it thanks